# Reinforcement learning with Q-learning doesn't seem to be learning

Tags: keras, tensorflow, openai-gym

I'm learning reinforcement learning with Q-learning and I made a training script for Flappy Bird. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be learning and I'm not sure why.
My guess is that there's something wrong in the Q-learning part where the model is trained, since it's something I didn't fully understand yet. I also tried a few other environments from Gymnasium but none of them trained, so I'm missing something fundamental about it.
Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I've been reading about how Q-learning is hard to get it right and I'm more and more insecure about this method.

Code:

```
import gc
import os
import random
from collections import deque
from keras import backend as k
import flappy_bird_gymnasium
import gymnasium
import numpy as np
from keras import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.initializers.initializers_v1 import HeUniform
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.losses import Huber
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.saving.legacy.save import load_model


def create_model():
    learning_rate = 0.001
    init = HeUniform()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=12, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=init))
    model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=init))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear', kernel_initializer=init))
    model.compile(loss=Huber(), optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


def choose_action(model, epsilon, state, training_mode):
    if np.random.rand() < epsilon and training_mode:
        return env.action_space.sample()
    else:
        return predict_action(model, np.reshape(state, (1, 12))).argmax()


def predict_action(model, state):
    actions = model.predict(state, verbose=0)
    return np.where(actions < 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)


class ClearMemory(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        gc.collect()
        k.clear_session()


def train_dnn(replay_memory, model, target_model):
    learning_rate = 0.7
    discount_factor = 0.618
    min_replay_size = 1000

    if len(replay_memory) < min_replay_size:
        return

    batch_size = 64
    mini_batch = random.sample(replay_memory, batch_size)
    current_states = np.array([transition[0] for transition in mini_batch])
    current_qs_list = predict_action(model, current_states)
    new_current_states = np.array([transition[3] for transition in mini_batch])
    future_qs_list = predict_action(target_model, new_current_states)

    x = []
    y = []
    for index, (observation, action, reward, new_observation, done) in enumerate(mini_batch):
        if not done:
            max_future_q = reward + discount_factor * np.max(future_qs_list[index])
        else:
            max_future_q = reward

        current_qs = current_qs_list[index]
        current_qs[action] = (1 - learning_rate) * current_qs[action] + learning_rate * max_future_q

        x.append(observation)
        y.append(current_qs)
    model.fit(np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y), batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, callbacks=ClearMemory())
    model.save(model_name)


# Create environment
env = gymnasium.make("FlappyBird-v0", audio_on=False)

# Load or create model
model_name = 'flappy_bird_model.h5'
if os.path.exists(model_name):
    print('Loading model...')
    model = load_model(model_name)
else:
    print('Creating model...')
    model = create_model()

# Create target model
target_model = create_model()

# Hyperparameters
n_episodes = 100000
epsilon = 1
max_epsilon = 1
min_epsilon = 0.01
decay = 0.00005
steps_to_update_target_model = 0
update_target_model_frequency = 100
replay_memory = deque(maxlen=2000)
render = False
training_mode = True

# Certain checkpoints to see if it's learning
max_scores = {15: 0, 14: 0, 13: 0, 12: 0, 11: 0, 10: 0, 9: 0, 8: 0}

for episode in range(n_episodes):
    state, _ = env.reset()
    total_reward = 0
    done = False
    episode_reward = 0

    while not done:
        if render:
            env.render()
        steps_to_update_target_model += 1
        action = choose_action(model, epsilon, state, training_mode)

        next_state, reward, done, _, _ = env.step(action)

        # Reward boost for staying in position to pass through the pipes
        up_pipe_position = next_state[1]
        down_pipe_position = next_state[2]
        player_position = next_state[9]
        is_between = up_pipe_position != 0.0 and down_pipe_position != 1.0 and player_position > 0 and up_pipe_position < player_position < down_pipe_position
        if not done and is_between:
            reward += 5
            print(f'up_pipe_position: {up_pipe_position}, '
                  f'down_pipe_position: {down_pipe_position}, '
                  f'player_position: {player_position}, '
                  f'is_between: {is_between}, '
                  f'reward: {reward}')

        replay_memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))
        total_reward += reward
        state = next_state

        if steps_to_update_target_model % update_target_model_frequency == 0 or done:
            train_dnn(replay_memory, model, target_model)

        # Decay epsilon so it explores less and less
        epsilon = min_epsilon + (max_epsilon - min_epsilon) * np.exp(-decay * episode)
        if done:
            print(f'New epsilon: {epsilon}')
            print(f'Episode {episode} finished with reward {total_reward}')

            for i in max_scores:
                if total_reward > i:
                    max_scores[i] += 1
                    break
            print(f'Best scores: {max_scores}')

            # Update target model
            if steps_to_update_target_model >= 100:
                target_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())
                steps_to_update_target_model = 0
            break

env.close()
```

This code is heavily based on [this minDQN project](https://github.com/mswang12/minDQN/blob/main/minDQN.py) and it uses [this Flappy Bird environment](https://github.com/markub3327/flappy-bird-gymnasium) and it's running on Windows 11 with Python 3.10.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are testing on a too-large example. You should take a very small but understandable example to solve your issue and monitor how the parameters evolve.

Comment: You mean change from Flappy Bird to something else? I also tried Car Racing based on [this project](https://github.com/andywu0913/OpenAI-GYM-CarRacing-DQN) but I didn't succeed, so I'm not sure which part I'm not getting right.  

About the code, when I debug current_qs_list and future_qs_list, I only see negative values. That means those are not good actions, right? If so, wouldn't that take at least hours to my model understand that some of those actions are necessary, therefore good? I'm not sure if it's me or in general (probably me), but Q-learning seems slow

Comment: Otherwise, you can run & compare it with another code. Check step by step the differences in the code and its output: https://github.com/uvipen/Flappy-bird-deep-Q-learning-pytorch